# Better way to pass data between Activities in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns

In my application I am fetching data from JavaScript, as it is not possible to return the data as an array or object, I am returning it as a String.

Now to organize the data I am creating a class which contains `ArrayList`s and other string variables and further I am creating array of my class objects variable to store multiple records.

```
public class Data {

    ArrayList<String> m_empArrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> m_depArrayList = new ArrayList();
    String m_time;
    String m_duration;

}

Data d = new Data();
```

What would be a good approach to pass the data between Activities? As `Intent`s and `ShredPrefrence`s are used to pass small units of data I am not considering it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement the `Parcelable` interface in your custom object and transmit it via an `Intent`.

Here is an example of a `Parcelable` object.

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {

    private String someString = null;
    private int someInteger = 0;

    public MyObject() {
        // perform initialization if necessary
    }

    private MyObject(Parcel in) {
        someString = in.readString();
        someInteger = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {

        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyObject(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }

    };

    // Getters and setters

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(someString);
        dest.writeInt(someInteger);
    }

}
```

Here is what happens. If you implement the `Parcelable` interface you have to create a private constructor which takes a [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) as a parameter. That `Parcel` holds all the serialized values.

You must implement the nested class `Parcelable.Creator` with the name `CREATOR` as this is going to be called by Android when recreating your object.

The method [`describeContents()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html#describeContents%28%29) is only of use in special cases. You can leave it as it is with a return value of `0`.

The interesting action happens in [`writeToParcel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html#writeToParcel%28android.os.Parcel,%20int%29) where you, as the name tells, write your data to a `Parcel` object.

Now you can just add your custom object directly to an `Intent` like in this example.

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setExtra("MY_OBJECT", myObject);
// implicit or explicit destination declaration
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Well thats really nice explanation , but i am confused between using Parcelable and Application class , so what do you suggest ?

Comment: I guess it heavily depends on the use case but in your case I'd recommend `Parcelables`.

Comment: Okay , as i have a pretty heavy data usage so i will go with the parcelables.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **Application** class present in Android to pass data between activities.

here is a good link..http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state

Comment: Thanks sujit for your information too , i didn't know about this.