# How to put a List in intent

Tags: android

I have a List in one of my activities and need to pass it to the next activity.

```
private List<Item> selectedData;
```

I tried putting this in intent by :

```
intent.putExtra("selectedData", selectedData);
```

But it is not working. What can be done?

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: It says **Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Item>**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to instantiate the `List` to a concrete type first. `List` itself is an interface.

If you [implement the `Parcelable` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435689/better-way-to-pass-data-between-activities-in-android/6437396#6437396) in your object then you can use the [`putParcelableArrayListExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) method to add it to the `Intent`.

Comment: No, I tried it. Didn't work. I also tried **view_order_intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("selectedData",  (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) selectedData);**. There came out to be no errors but I am not able to get it.

Comment: **selectedData = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedData");**. I tried this to get the code. I didn't work.

Comment: List is the parent of ArrayList.. The method specifically wants ArrayList.. Just change the type of List to ArrayList

Comment: `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("XXX", (ArrayList<Item>)yourList);` (assuming `Item` is `Parcelable`)

Answer (score 14):

Like howettl mentioned in a comment, if you make the object you are keeping in your list serializeable then it become very easy. Then you can put it in a Bundle which you can then put in the intent. Here is an example:

```
class ExampleClass implements Serializable {
    public String toString() {
        return "I am a class";
    }
}

... */ Where you wanna create the activity /*

ExampleClass e = new ExampleClass();
ArrayList<ExampleClass> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(e);
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializeable(l);
i.putExtra("LIST", b);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Actually, it must be `b.putSerialzeable("key", l)` and it should be noted that to access your list in the other activity, you have to do `List<ExampleClass> listExtra = (ArrayList<ExampleClass>)( intent.getBundleExtra("LIST").getSerializable("key"))`. Still, its much easier than implementing Parceable for your ExampleClass.

Answer (score 4):

i think ur item should be  parcelable. and you should use arraylist instead of list.
then use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra

Comment: An example will be really useful.

Comment: You could also make the item implement `Serializable` and it becomes trivial

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
//first create the list to put objects
private ArrayList<ItemCreate> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

//on the sender activity
     //add items to list where necessary also make sure the Class model ItemCreate implements Serializable
     itemsList.add(theInstanceOfItemCreates);

        Intent goToActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        goToActivity.putExtra("ITEMS", itemsList);
                        startActivity(goToActivity);

    //then on second activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
            receivedItemsList = (ArrayList<ItemCreate>) i.getSerializableExtra("ITEMS");
            Log.d("Print Items Count", receivedItemsList.size()+"");
            for (Received item:
                 receivedItemList) {
                Log.d("Print Item name: ", item.getName() + "");
        }
```

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone says that you can use Serializable, but none mentioned that you can just cast the value to Serializable instead of list.

```
intent.putExtra("selectedData", (Serializable) selectedData);
```

Core's lists implementations already implement Serializable, so you're not bound to a specific implementation of list, but remember that you still can catch ClassCastException.