# how to passing list<> in bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, bundle

I have the following code:

```
List<ValueActivity> list = new ArrayList<ValueActivity>();    
list = setList();    
Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);    
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.put ????("list", list);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

How to write line 5 and how getExtra in destination intent

Comment: Is `ValueActivity` class is implementing  serializable or parcelable interface ?

Comment: what have you try with this line 5?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541088/how-to-put-a-list-in-intent

Comment: another possible solution, if the list is not too long, create one String from the list, where everything from the list is put together and separated with a delimeter. Than You can pass a simple String and get the elements by String.split()

Comment: public class ValueActivity {
    private int id;
    private String nameP, nameA;
    private int hourS;

    public String get_nameP() {
        return nameP;
    }


    public void set_nameP(String nameP) {
        this.nameP = nameP;
    }


    public String get_nameA() {
        return nameA;
    }


    public void set_nameA(String nameA) {
        this.nameA = nameA;
    }


}

Comment: how to use put in line 5

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will need to have `ValueActivity` implement `Parcelable` interface and you will need to implement `writeToParcel()` the `CREATOR` and a suitable constructor that takes a `Parcel` as argument. See the documentation of `Parcelable` interface.

To put the list into the `Bundle`, use:

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", list);
```

To get the list out of the `Bundle` in the target activity, use:

```
List<ValueActivity> = listbundle.getParcelableArrayList("list");
```

Comment: FYI putParcelableArrayList takes an ArrayList, not a List.

Answer (score 13):

try to use :

```
String jsonList = gson.toJson(youList);
// Add String to bundle
```

Comment: Perfect solution.