# Access List<List<String>> using this keyword

Tags: java, android, list, this

Lets assume that I store values to List A, List B & List C through for loop.
List A,B,C values is added by the following way:

```
for (int j = 0; j <5; j++) 
{
   list_A.add("Value"+i);
   list_B.add("Value"+i);
   list_C.add("Value"+i);
}
```

To access the List out of the method I'm using **this** keyword by the following way:

```
private CharSequence ListA[]; // declaration    
this.ListA= list_A.toArray(new CharSequence[list_A.size()]); //accessing with this keyword
```

Now I am adding all these list to another List by the following way

```
List<List<String>> finallist = new ArrayList<>();
finallist .add(list_A);
finallist .add(list_B);
finallist .add(list_C);
```

I did some searching but I couldn't find how to declare and access   List< List< String>> using this keyword?

**Note**: It is the actual modification of the question that I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137823/how-to-get-listliststring-with-this-keyword). As I couldn't get any answer, I thought I could make it bit simple and have raised the question here.

Comment: Declarations have nothing to do with the `this` keyword, and where you are using it here it is redundant.

Comment: I'm using it for fragment. I have asked a question already in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137823/how-to-get-listliststring-with-this-keyword?noredirect=1#comment71442116_42137823

Comment: 'Using it for fragment' doesn't make any more sense than the rest of the question, which is a duplicate. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You use the this keyword to access a member of method of the current instance of the class.  You would only do that inside of a function-  because outside of a function the this keyword isn't defined.

Generally you don't actually use this.variable or this.method.  You only need to do that if another variable at overriding scope uses the same name.  Generally you see this in autogenerated setters/constructors and not much else-  its easier just not to reuse the name.

Comment: Please look into this , as i need to access it outside for fragment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137823/how-to-get-listliststring-with-this-keyword?noredirect=1#comment71442116_42137823

Comment: The this keyword has absolutely nothing to do with what you want.  You need to learn to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a variable of one class in another, you could do something like this:

### Main Class

```
public static final List<String> list_A = new ArrayList<>();
static{
    for (int j = 0; j <5; j++) 
    {
        list_A.add("Value"+i);
    }
}
```

### Fragment Class

```
CharSequence ListA[];
ListA = MainClass.list_A.toArray(new CharSequence[MainClass.list_A.size()]);
```

I would recommend using the `static` keyword in the declaration of `list_A`

Comment: Someone beat me to it.

Comment: I need to use it for fragment. Have explained it in detail here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137823/how-to-get-listliststring-with-this-keyword?noredirect=1#comment71442116_42137823

Comment: I don't understand why these people are just saying "Your question sucks" and not actually helping you.

Comment: I could able to access List A,B,C. But how to access the final list where I have added all the list to that list ?

Comment: Just access it. Use `MainClass.list_A/B/C` to get each list, and then add them to the list in your Fragment, or create the `finallist` in your MainClass and access that the exact same way.

Comment: I have done that but I need to pass the Final List to a bundle , so i need to know how to get the  List< List< String>> . Can u please refer the link which I have given in Note in my question and tell me how would I pass latest_list to the bundle ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190847/how-to-passing-list-in-bundle

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I can already pass the List to the bundle. I just want to know how to pass < List < List >>  also the Line that should come after Line no 18 in my actual question. How would I assign it in this keyword .

Comment: You don't. I can only recommend that you take Android Java online courses or watch YouTube videos. You'll learn more by looking, not asking.

Comment: I have edited my actual question. Now can you please help me with (1) and (2) which I have marked as comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to display your code, because the scopes really matter in this case. Whether or not you need the this keyword is highly dependent on where things are declared.

Answer (score 0):

`this.ListA` means that you want to access field `ListA` of `this` object.
If you declare a variable as `List<List<String>> finallist = new ArrayList<>();` inside some method, then it is **not** a field of `this` object, and you can't access it with `this` keyword. If you want to access it outside the method, you should declare it as a class field.

It is Java-very-basics thing about classes, fields and `this`. You should learn Java very basics to eliminate hundreds of questions like this, on which you will loose a lot of time. Much more than to learn very basics.