# How do you pass a List<Placeholder> to a bundle if Placeholder is already an interface

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bundle

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190847/how-to-passing-list-in-bundle) the recommended solution is to have Placeholder implement the Parcelable interface.
However in my case Placeholder is already an interface and thus cannot implement the Parcelable interface.

Comment: Interfaces don't implement other interfaces, they extend them.

Comment: Do you have properties for your interface Why don't you pass implementation of Interface

Answer (score 0):

Differently than classes, whereas you cannot have one class extending from two or more classes, interfaces can extend multiple interfaces.

The syntax is very easy:

```
public interface A {
}

public interface B {
}

public interface C extends A, B {
}
```

Also bear in mind that a class can implement multiple interfaces.