# Sending ArrayList with intent putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an android application and I am trying to send an array to another intent. I want to show them in a listview.

How i can achive that?

I have 2 problems.

1. How to send them to be able later to show them
2. How to show datas via listview.

On the first activity, when I log out the data its okay.

On the second activity, when i log out the received data, i got null.
When I run the app, force close.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

First activity:

```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(selectImages));


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this,Upload.class);
                    intent.putExtra("mylist", selectImages);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Second activity:

```
public class Upload extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("mylist");

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("data","UPLOAD:"+list);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
putParcelableArrayListExtra()
```

Check @ Jordi Castilla comment

**EDIT 1**

[here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/28/pass-arraylist-activity-android/) is the clear Example

Comment: cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String,java util.List<java.lang.String>)'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541088/how-to-put-a-list-in-intent

Comment: tried every possible way like in that post, nothing worked so far :/

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15790688/3981656

Comment: i made a printscreen of the error, http://i.imgur.com/ASKSW3c.png

Comment: try with edited answer

Comment: its working now, but again just the last item is being sent. i logged the first page, its okay, but when i sent the data, just the last selected one arrived..

Comment: this is the receiving:  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(b!=null){
            ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>)b.getStringArrayList("array_list");
            Log.i("adat","UPLOAD:"+arr);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }