# how to print only name from hashmap java

Tags: java, android-studio

This is mainActivity and i am passing data(contactList) to second activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();


}


/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }



@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString("id");
                String name = c.getString("name");
                String email = c.getString("email");
                String address = c.getString("address");
                String gender = c.getString("gender");

                // Phone node is JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                String home = phone.getString("home");
                String office = phone.getString("office");


                // tmp hash map for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("id", id);
                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("email", email);
                contact.put("mobile", mobile);
                contact.put("address", address);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("array", contactList);
    startActivity(in);


    return null;
```

}

I want to print just address from this array but I am having a problem to print just address, it is printing the whole ArrayList

```
Intent intent = getIntent();


if(intent!=null){
            ArrayList tmp = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array");


        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tmp));

        System.out.println(tmp);


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541088/how-to-put-a-list-in-intent

Comment: tim that isnt working for me

Comment: Can you put your HashMap here to see what it looks like?

Comment: @nassertahani i have uploaded the mainActivity