# Return list from a Activity to Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I want `MainActivity` call a `SecondActivity` and the `SecondActivity` return a List of Strings.

Every answer that I have read explains how to pass data from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`.

I have created an Activity that calculate all possible IPs in internal network and keep them to a List.
I want to pass this List to `MainActivity`.
Could you suggest me some links or code to solve my problem?
I am totally new at Android Studio but I have to do it.
Here the snippet code from **MainActivity**

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean check_conn = false;
                    check_conn = checkInternetConnection();//check if you are on internet

                    if (check_conn){
                        //we have connection
                        // find the all the possible IPs
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, rangeIP_test.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        // do something annoying
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "We need Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The **rangeIP_test** Activity that calculate IPs

```
WifiManager my_wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String subnet = getSubnetAddress(my_wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway);
IPs = findIP(subnet);

public List<String> findIP(String subnet){
        List<String> all_IPs;// All IPs on network
        all_IPs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=2; i<255; i++){
            String host = subnet + "." + i;

            all_IPs.add(host);
        }
        return all_IPs;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a List in intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541088/how-to-put-a-list-in-intent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the activity, `rangeIP_test`, for a result(i.e., list of strings of hosts) like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, rangeIP_test.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent,RC_LIST_STRING);
```

Define RC_LIST_STRING as a field like this in `MainActivity.java`:

```
 private static final int RC_LIST_STRING = 10001;
```

Override [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) in `MainActivity.java` like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == RC_LIST_STRING) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               // get the list of strings here
               ArrayList<String> myHosts = (ArrayList<String>) data.getSerializableExtra("myHosts"); // key must be matching 
               // do operations on the list
            }
        }
    }
```

In `rangeIP_test.java`, after successfully getting all the hosts and adding them into a list, you can pass the list back to whichever activity(here, `MainActivity`) started the current activity(here, `rangeIP_test`) like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myHosts", (Serializable) IPs);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Now, that you've finished `rangeIP_test` activity, you're back to `MainActivity` and since you've overriden `onActivityResult()`, you'll get the list of hosts over there.

Bear in mind that, in this example, you're converting a list of hosts into a serialized type and passing it to previous activity. Since [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) already implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface, you won't get any `unable to marshal value` [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819146/5990846).
However, while passing your model objects around activities, you need to first make the model class implement `Serializable` interface and then proceed further as above.

The better approach is to convert model classes into **Parcelable** and then pass the data among activities. Please refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable) for more info.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed answer and your time! Thank you so much @Jay I wasted too much time to find the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I have to mention that in command intent.putExtra("myHosts", all_IPs); I got an error and I try the four solution that AS suggests. It work when I make the list Serializable.

Comment: @OrfeasKazepis could you edit my answer to remove the above error? So that others won't get that error again.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass list into intent extras

something like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<String>) all_IPs);
```

in another activity, you can receive it like below

```
ArrayList<String> test = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Comment: we need to use 
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
also right ?

Answer (score 1):

Using startActivityForResult and onActivityResult may works.

call rangeIP_test Activity by startActivityForResult()
and return your list by setResult(). Don't forget to finish() when jobs done.